# How to check constraints on dexterity content types fields

Tags: plone

I want to check during edit form saving process the value of a field verify some constraints

(understand calling a method where I can invalidate the form action)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The field must be defined via schema (not supermodel), otherwise the field isn't visible in the schema. Once the field is defined in the schema, you may use a decorated function like the following to set a field validator:

```
@form.validator(field=IMySchema['title'])
def validateTitle(value):
    if value == value.upper():
        raise schema.ValidationError(u"Please don't shout")
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you can do this with a filesystem code dexterity type using [zope.interface invariants](http://docs.zope.org/zope.interface/README.html#invariants).

Comment: Oops, I misread, if you just want to validate one field, SteveM is right.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Dexterity Developer Manual, on the chapter dedicated to [validators](http://plone.org/products/dexterity/documentation/manual/developer-manual/advanced/validators).